# Measurability of multifunction

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose $ f (.,x, u) $ is Lebesgue measurable for each $(x,u)$. Suppose also that $ f $ is continuous at $ (x, u) $ for each fixed $t$.

Let $ g: [a, b] \rightarrow [a, b] $ be a Lebesgue measurable function and $ U: [a, b] \rightrightarrows \mathbb {R}^{m} $ be a Lebesgue measurable multifunction. Then the multifunction
$$
F(t,x) = f(g(t),x,U(t))
$$
é  $\mathcal{L}\times \mathcal{B}^{n}$-measurable (Lebesgue-Borel)? Or should require continuity in $ t $ in the function $ f $?

Obs: Let $H: \Omega \rightrightarrows \mathbb {R}^{n} $ and  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. $H$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable if for each compact set $K \subset \mathbb {R}^{n}$,
$$
\{x \in \Omega: H(x) \cap K \not= \emptyset\} \in \mathcal{F}.
$$

Comment: What notion of measurability for multifunctions do you use?

Comment: Castaing-Valadier

Comment: This was [crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131012/measurable-multifunction). In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: I asked this question in the mathoverflow also   http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131012/measurable-multifunction